# If I include jQuery via bookmarklet, will it ruin the original javascript on the site?

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet

I'm creating a bookmarklet and of course I'd like to use jQuery. But, if I include jQuery (append a script-tag to head) on a site, will the site itself work anymore, if it has some other js on?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it break?....**maybe** :)

There are 2 really common reasons off the top of my head that this would happen.  If they're using another library that uses the `$` for it's main object then you'll get a conflict, this however is resolvable with [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); //give `$` back to whatever had it...
$j("selector").doSomething(); //use the $j you assigned or jQuery from now on
```

The other one would be they already have jQuery loaded (possibly a different version as well).  I would just add a `jQuery` object test before loading your script, like this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { //load jQuery }
//jQuery has been loaded, either by your or originally, keep going...
```

This solution for already loaded has one caveat, if they had an *old* version of jQuery, you'll only have the features of that version.  I don't know of a way to load an old version and a new one in the page and not have a lot of weird behavior...it just wasn't designed to do that.

Also, I would combine these two work-arounds for the case that jQuery is already loaded and *is* the `$`, like this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
  var used = typeof $ != 'undefined';
  //load jQuery 
  if(used) jQuery.noConflict();
}
window.$j = jQuery;
//always use $j in your script, it'll always be present.
```

Comment: What about this?
$j(document).ready(function(){ //Here stuff like $(selector) }
Isn't that okay?

Comment: @Martti - You can wrap your code so the $ works inside of it, like this:  `(function($) { $(function() { /* document.ready stuff */ }); /* other stuff using $() */ })(jQuery);`

Comment: Assuming i want also load jQuery UI, which could be already loaded or not, how can i extend the above code so that all possibilities are checked and both libraries are always present?

Comment: @Alp - in that case you're checking for `typeof jQuery.ui` instead of just `jQuery`

Comment: But how do i tell jQuery UI that jQuery is located in the custom namespace `$j`?